# OpenShift-Ansible with MS Active Directory

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

**Environment:**

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Atomic Host"
VERSION="7.3"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Atomic Host"
VARIANT_ID=atomic.host
VERSION_ID="7.3"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Atomic Host 7.3"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.3:GA:atomic-host"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.3
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.3
```

**OpenShift-Ansible Version:**

```
3.6.11-1
```

This is openshift-ansible setup with Atomic hosts, so OpenShift itself is containerized.

**Question:**

Has anyone configured OpenShift using OpenShift-Ansible for MS Active Directory? I found this reference, but it implies that OpenShift master node service runs under systemd:

http://www.greenreedtech.com/openshift-origin-active-directory-integration/

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

(Unfortunately, I don't have ability to test it but) [OpenShift documentation says](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/rpm_vs_containerized.html#containerized-starting-and-stopping-containers) that

> The installation process creates relevant systemd units which can be used to start, stop, and poll services **using normal systemctl commands**.

So, I'd expect that command `systemctl restart origin-master` should work (except, in your case it will be `atomic-openshift-master`)

It also says that

> **configuration files are placed in the same locations** during containerized installation as RPM based installations

so I'd expect that this instruction would work.

Comment: Ah Spasibo Slava!

Comment: reloading worked. I added my userid to cluster-admin group. However, for some reason still getting 401 error :(